# UIAlertview not accepting string as message

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have this response from my webservice but UIAlertview is giving an strange error

I have printed the respnse and just below I called

```
2013-08-13 15:40:27.463 Ipad Qld[1459:907] Result {
    msg = "Form has been sent successfully.";
    status = SUCCESS;
}

2013-08-13 15:40:27.465 Ipad Qld[1459:907] -[__NSDictionaryM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f1168e0
2013-08-13 15:40:27.467 Ipad Qld[1459:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f1168e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x32dad2a3 0x3ac1197f 0x32db0e07 0x32daf531 0x32d06f68 0x34bb9375 0x34d05c95 0x34d05741 0x6a25b 0x32cfe037 0x336ae2cb 0xa013f 0x9fe35 0x8d1e7 0x336e86fd 0x336281f9 0x33628115 0x32a8a45f 0x32a89b43 0x32ab1fcb 0x32cf374d 0x32ab242b 0x32a1603d 0x32d82683 0x32d81f7f 0x32d80cb7 0x32cf3ebd 0x32cf3d49 0x368aa2eb 0x34c09301 0x43a85 0x3b048b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

the code is

```
- (void) contactUsNotificationReceived:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    [[ActivityIndicator currentIndicator] hide];

    NSDictionary *alertMessage = [notification userInfo];
    NSString * alertMessageString = alertMessage[@"NSLocalizedString"];

    NSLog(@"Result is waga %@",alertMessageString);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result" message:alertMessageString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Show your code otherwise it is just a guess for us.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to set webresponse to `alertView.message` which is a dictionary `Result { msg = "Form has been sent successfully."; status = SUCCESS; }`. Get webresponse in **id** and then `NSString *message = [response objectForKey:@"msg"];`

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", alertMessage);` tell me what does it print ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are passing a `NSDictionnary`.
A guess, try to change :

```
NSString * alertMessage; // the object that you think is a NSString
```

to

```
NSDictionary * alertMessage;
NSString * alertMessageString = alertMessage[@"msg"];
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems like problem in `isEqualToString`. The source string is not valid or it is released or its now pointing to `Dictionary`.

May be your alert string *(that you want to describe)* it is not `NSString` but it may be `NSDictionary`, so check it.

Answer (score 1):

First get your alert message from NSDictionary to NSString...

```
  NSString *alertMessage = [yourDict objectForKey:@"yourKey"];
```

Now, show your alert Message in Alert...

```
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",alertMessage] message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
```

I hope this will help you.